# If X, Y and Z are sets, prove set related questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

1. not Z ⊆ not Y implies Y ⊆ Z by contradiction
2. not Z ⊆ not Y implies X ∩ Y ⊆ X ∩ Z  (using part 1)

So far for 1 I have if not Z is subset of not Y then all elements of not Z are in not Y which means all elements not Z must not be in Y which means all elements of Y must be in Z. Is this correct? And how would I go about part 2?

EDIT: not Z would mean the complement of Z within an universal set U

Comment: What is "*not Z*"?  Do you mean to have some universal set $\Omega$ and you mean to talk about the complement of $Z$ which is written as $Z^c=\Omega\setminus Z = \{a\mid a\in \Omega,~a\not\in Z\}$?

Comment: As for "*is this correct*" for your attempt for 1, you have not proven anything.  You just used the result that you are trying to prove in the proof for itself and is circular reasoning.  Approach from first principles.

Answer (score 1):

That's not bad but is not "by contradiction".

If Y is not a subset of Z then there exist some y that is in Y but is not in Z. So y is in "not Z" but is not in "not  Y".  That contradicts the fact that "not Z" is a subset of "not Y".

For (2),  if "not Z" is a subset of "not Y" then, by 1, Y is a subset of Z.  If $x\in X\cap Y$ then x is in X and x is in Y.  Since Y is a subset of Z, x is in Z.  Since x is in X and in Z it is in $X\cap Z$.